# "Object doesn't support this action" for a drop down menu in Excel 2011 (Mac OS X)

Tags: excel, vba, macos, excel-2011

I have a big Excel Workbook made with Office 2010 with some VBA code. Everything seems to work fine apart the drop down menus. Precisely, they work, graphically, but

```
Me.Shapes("Drop Down 1").ControlFormat
```

throws an "Object doesn't support this action" error (I am sure that "Drop Down 1" is the correct name, etc.), precisely, it gets referenced correctly (e.g. `shape = Me.Shapes(1)` works) but it doesn't seem to like `ControlFormat`. Google doesn't help much; any suggestions?

I'm quite new to VBA so there might be some trivial debugging witchcraft I'm not aware of.

**EDIT**: I tried creating a new workbook with a dummy dropdown menu and selecting the values whilst recording a macro but it gives no result (it's like the menu never existed).

Comment: try `? Me.Shapes(1).Name` in the immediate window (Ctrl+G) to see if you have the correct name at the point the error occurs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this can sound frustrating and Stupid at the same time but for Excel 2011, change the line from

`Me.Shapes("Drop Down 1").ControlFormat`

to

`Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes("Drop Down 1").ControlFormat`

For example

This will work in Excel 2010 but not in Excel 2011

```
Sub Sample()
    With Me.Shapes("Drop Down 1").ControlFormat
        .AddItem "Sid"
    End With
End Sub
```

It will give you the error that you mentioned.

**SCREENSHOT**

[image]

For Excel 2011, you will have to use (*Fully qualify the object*)

```
Sub Sample()
    With Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes("Drop Down 1").ControlFormat
        .AddItem "Sid"
    End With
End Sub
```

**SCREENSHOT**

[image]

**Note**: Replace `Sheet1` above with the relevant sheet name.

Comment: Are there a list of difference/comparsion between Excel 2010 and Excel 2011 on Mac?

Comment: that is absolutely silly. thank you very much! I have NO IDEA how I could have done otherwise :)

Comment: Do you happen to know why the first way does not work on Mac? Is there a reason for this?

Comment: @amb110395: I do not know why it doesn't work in Excel 2011. But then lot of things do not work on Excel 2011. I guess it is the way MS has coded it.